# iterate a function through group of rows in python

Tags: loops, indexing, pandas-groupby, rows

I have a dataset with four columns: treatment (hr), time (t), an independent variable (y), and std.deviation (s_y). Treatment includes 2 groups, A and B.

I have defined a function (model) and I want to fit it to my data (y). I want to apply the function to the groups under column treatment. I thought about using 'groupby' to group y based on treatment. However, my function needs a parameter, K, which is defined based on index. For example, it has to correspond to 3rd value in the list of y. As I want to make subgroups based on treatment, I should get a  different K for each subgroup. I am not able to apply the reset.index() option to groupby, so I don't know how can I tell my function to get the 3rd value of y for each subgroup.

Is there a more efficient way to loop the function over the different groups in treatment?

This is the code:

```
this is my df: 

  treatment  time      y     std_y 
    A         1        2.29   0.30
    A         2        2.68   0.29
    A         3        2.79   0.29 
    B         1        2.25   0.07
    B         2        2.53   0.07 
    B         3        2.55   0.07  



for i, g in df.groupby('treatment'):
    def model (t, m, B, n):
        k = 0.2 
        return K*np.exp(-m*t) + B*np.exp(-n*t)
# k is the parameter that I would like to define based on index for each group in treatment.  
# It has to correspond to the 3rd element of y, and it should be a different value for group (A and B).

    fit = curve_fit(model, g['time'], g['y'],
                sigma=g['std_y'],
                p0=None)

    ans,cov = fit
    fit_m, fit_B, fit_n = ans
```

Comment: The 3rd element is for the example (means the last row in the group) or `k` always will be the 3rd element, no matter the shape of the group?

Comment: K will always be the 3rd element, no matter the shape of the group. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your `curve_fit` do but as a quick example you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'treatment': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'time': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
        'y': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'std_y': [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

for i, g in df.groupby('treatment'):
    def model(t, m, b, n):
        return k*np.exp(-m*t) + b*np.exp(-n*t)

    k = g.iloc[2].y
    print('k:', k, 'model_out:', model(t=1, m=2, b=4, n=4))

    fit = curve_fit(model, g['time'], g['y'], sigma=g['std_y'], p0=None)
    ans, cov = fit
    fit_m, fit_B, fit_n = ans
```

**NOTE**: As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) says, the groupby function doesn't change the order of the observations, so you need to consider sort your dataset before using it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Very helpful, but I am still a bit confused. The function curve fit calculates the best parameters that fit the model (based on my data). They should be three parameters: m,n and B.  I need to calculate these parameters because I use them later on. I am not sure how to calculate them based on your script. How do you suggest to call the curve_fit function inside fun? I tried like this:

Comment: I basically added to your code the following, which replaces the last two lines of fun with: 
    
    fit = curve_fit(fun, df['time'], df['y'], sigma = df['std_y], p0 = None) /
    ans, cov = fit / 
    fit_m, fit_B, fit_n = ans/ 
    return ans/

Comment: I changed the code to provide you a solution closer to your current code, hope this help!

Comment: Hi @Martina Lazzarin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.